# How to make SVG sprite image for multiple graphics?

Tags: image, user-interface, svg, sprite, graphic

We have been using png format for sprite image. But we need svg icons in sprite for better quality. Is it possible to make svg sprite with multiple graphics?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  If loaded as an `<image>` or `background-image`, the browser treats an SVG file identically to a bitmap image.